How to create ItemReader for reading JSON file which not start or end with array ([ ])
I have a problem on reading JSON file which not start with array ([]). For example I have JSON file with this format.
{  foo: [],  bar: {},  baz: {},  .... }
I want to create a ItemReader which can read the JSON file and loop through the foo field on Spring Batch Chunk
I have tried to read it using Jackson bind Object Mappern than return each of the array item. But it result in repeating more than it needed to.

Could you provide some more details on your input data, the bind object, and the output that "repeats more than it needed"?

The input data is like the format that I mention before, where the foo field have 1 array item. When I run it using batch, it generate more than one row of data. I expect it to just generate 1 row of data because just 1 array item present in the JSON foo.
